# Missing dll's for Texmaker/Miktex - The code execution cannot proceed

Tags: miktex, texmaker, missing, kpathsea

I have Texmaker and MiKTeX installed. I downloaded all available MiKTeX packages. When building the doc in Texmaker, I get:

> The code execution cannot proceed because MikTeX200629-png.dll / MikTeX200629-web2c.dll / MikTeX200629-poppler.dll / MikTeX200629-kpathsea.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

I have reinstalled both MiKTeX and Texmaker twice already, and I have re-downloaded the packages. I have also tried every solution I could find relating to the problem, all to no avail.

Comment: can you compile on the command line?

Comment: No, I get the exact same error using "pdflatex example.tex"   @UlrikeFischer

Comment: In a current miktex the dll have names like `MiKTeX200700-png.dll` so run an update and check for new package (if you have a multiuser installation do it in admin mode).

Comment: I have done so, but  no updates are available. All my packages were installed in admin mode. This is happening since I updated Miktex Console to basic-miktex-20.6.29-x64. Where should these dll's be located? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: the dll are in my miktex bin folder. miktex 20.7 has been released https://miktex.org/announcement/miktex-20-7 begin of august. Did you check your dll? Do you have 200700? Then you perhaps need to recreate the wrappers.

Comment: I have all of the MiKTeX200700 dll's in the bin folder. There also are some "MiKTeX200629-___.dll.(old) "  ones. I presume that Texmaker is still looking for the 200629 dll's after updating MikTeX.  Do you maybe have a resource explaining how to recreate the wrappers? Thank you so much for your help! @UlrikeFischer

Comment: do you have a single or a multi user miktex installation?

Comment: I only have one user account on my PC, but I installed all packages using administrator mode. So I suppose that it counts as a multi user installation. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: well not sure, try `initexmf --report` to find out if you have a SharedSetup or not. Then try `initexmf --admin --force --mklinks` (or without the admin). But as you have both variants of dll, I suspect that you mixed two miktex versions, and it is quite unclear in which state your system is (reinstalling again and again is often not really the best idea).

Comment: Thank you so much, 'initexmf --admin --force --mklinks', combined with resetting texmaker settings fixed it!  I've been struggling with this for ages, thanks so much!  

P.S.: The reason I uninstalled miktex is because I read that previous versions have to be uninstalled before installing a later version @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The executables like `pdflatex.exe` are small wrappers. If they complain about missing/wrong dll's (e.g. after an update) it can help to recreate them with

```
 initexmf --admin --force --mklinks
```

Comment: remove --admin if not in shared MiKTeX setup.

Comment: Whyever the setup executable does not run this itself is completely beyond me.